# use JQuery to wordpress admin page wp-admin

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I would like to add some jQuery to wordpress/woocommerce admin page. The code works good on the client page but never pass to wp-admin page.

This is the code:

```
 jQuery("#postbox-container-1").ready(function(){
      alert("now what?");
        
      $('p:contains("Poivre")').css('color', 'red');
     
    });
```

Comment: You need to enqueue the script on the admin section. `add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'your_enqueue_function' );`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add custom javascript to WordPress Admin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326967/how-to-add-custom-javascript-to-wordpress-admin)

Comment: i used the following code but it did not work ... 

`add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts',
             jQuery("#postbox-container-1").ready(function(){
         $('p:contains("Poivre")').css('color', 'red');
     
    }));`

still not getting it...

Comment: That's not how enqueuing scripts work. You need to pass in a php function. Read the duplicate link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use WP `admin_footer` action hook to add custom js to the admin side. check below code. code will go in the active theme functions.php file.

```
function add_custom_admin_js(){
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function($){
            $("#postbox-container-1").ready(function(){
                alert("now what?");  
                $('p:contains("Poivre")').css('color', 'red');
            });
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
    <?php
}

add_action( 'admin_footer', 'add_custom_admin_js', 10, 1 );
```